# Is this sound card good enough?

Tags: home-studio, digital, spdif, optical

We have a sound system with 6.1 channels (7.1 if we use two active speakers in addition to the sub-woofer.) We're going to use the optical SPDIF connection. Are some sound cards better than others if they use optical SPDIF, because they don't do any DAC? In other words, are there any benefits of paying more for a [sound card](http://www.komplett.no/k/ki.aspx?sku=587208#extra) when we use the digital output?

Comment: I re-worded the question to better fit the scope of this site.  Questions about home theater are definitely off topic, but questions about surround sound are fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digital is digital, so if you are using an optical cable between your sound card and sound system, you should be fine.

But don't trust me, grab a S/PDIF cable and hook it up. How does it sounds?

There are two main reasons for using external sound cards, neither of which apply to your situation.

1. External sound cards allow you to isolate the analog signal path from the high-frequency digital noise generated by your computer. You aren't using the analog output, so this isn't an issue for you.
2. External sound cards give you more space for I/O ports. My MOTU 828 has 12 ins, 10 outs, S/PDIF in/out and ADAT in/out, plus some other random stuff like MIDI and various clocking options. You don't need any of this stuff.

Update:

Another consideration is that 5.1 and up surround sound audio is going to be compressed when it is transmitted over the optical S/PDIF cable. I'm not familiar enough with the DVD and Blu-Ray specs to know whether the on-disc audio is compressed using the same codec, but I'd guess that it is. If it is, then switching to a sound card with individual analog outs for each channel won't improve your sound quality because you are already dealing with a compressed data stream.

Comment: I only have a jack out..

Comment: What kind of "jack out"? Is it S/PDIF, analog only, or one of those combined analog/digital jacks like on a Macbook Pro?

Comment: 3.5mm: http://images.junostatic.com/full/IS296700-01-01-BIG.jpg

Comment: OK, by posting a picture of a 3.5mm plug, I assume you mean that the only output on your computer is analog audio. In that case, you probably want [something like this](http://www.amazon.com/Turtle-Beach-Advantage-Digital-Adapter/dp/B0036VO4X4).

Comment: But do you know about any systems like that with SPDIF 7.1 instead of 5.1? And 24 bit with 96 000 Hz?

Comment: According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolby_Digital_Plus#Physical_transport), the only way to transport 7.1 is via HDMI.

Comment: Too bad, because I have HDMI, but my projector doesn't have any audio out..

Comment: Does your sound system have HDMI in?

Comment: No :( That's the problem. It doesn't.

Comment: ok, then you probably want to stick with 5.1 over optical S/PDIF or get an audio interface that breaks all 8 channels out into 3.5mm jacks. But you want to keep those analog cable runs short!

Comment: Yes, I know... :( I'm a sound engineer myself, but I haven't looked much into home cinemas and so on yet..